# How to point app to promoted RDS replica without downtime or data loss

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using RDS with a read replica to perform some DDL operations on database schema, mainly adding columns to a table, without table locking or performance impact.

Now I want to promote the read replica to be a master on its own and point my application to the new promoted database, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Promote). However, the docs say:

> The promotion process can take several minutes or longer to complete, depending on the size of the Read Replica

I understand that, while the replica is being promoted, the changes from the source are not being replicated. So the new database won't have the records that were inserted during the replica promotion, and before I point my app to the new database.

Is there any way I can prevent the data loss while moving from one database to the other, apart from scheduling downtime in my app?

Comment: Which DB engine do you use in RDS?
Remember that you should only stop writing to the DB, you can keep on reading and serving from it. Therefore, it is not really a downtime of the app, just on data update.

Comment: I use MySQL. I run a webservice where writes to the DB are the most frequent operation. Is there a way to just "delay" these writes?

Comment: You can write the updates into a buffer (queue of SQL commands, for example) and execute them by a worker that is reading the tasks from the buffer. You can implement such system with a proxy that will simulate the DB connection and will push to the buffer (for example, with AWS SQS).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in your situation, it is unnecessary to promote a slave. If all you want to is to avoid locking during ALTER, you can use Percona's [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) tool to do the job to you.

The tool will create a new table, copy data there, and then swap the old and new tables. It works pretty smooth.

```
 pt-online-schema-change -h myrds-001.ccxyxyx14.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --print --alter-foreign-keys-method rebuild_constraints --alter "ADD COLUMN mycolumn1 VARCHAR(36), MODIFY COLUMN mycolumn2 VARCHAR(36)" --set-vars "foreign_key_checks=false" --recurse 0  --execute  D=mydb,t=mytable
```

If it is still locking, try this tool [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) as it using binary logs instead of triggers.